# Difficult! Unexpected speed reduction on transferring list synthesis to function

Tags: python, performance, search

I wrote a code that is supposed to do some operation on a sentence of a file and elements of two lists - `keywords` and `keywords2`. It is as follows -

```
import os
keywords=['a','b']
keywords2=['c','d mvb']

def foo(sentence,k2):

    gs_list=[]                       #####
    for k in keywords:               #####    
        if k in sentence:            #####
            gs_list.append(k)        #####

    for k in gs_list:
        if (k in sentence) and (k2 in sentence):
            print 'a match'
    return 4

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(r'F:\M.Tech\for assigning cl\selected\random 100'):
    for file in files:
        sentences=open(file).readlines();
        for sentence in sentences:
            if sentence.startswith('!series_title'):      
                for k2 in keywords2:
                    foo(sentence,k2)
```

I have marked the part of the code in question. This piece (let's call it BETA) basically forms a list of keywords which *are* in the sentence selected. As a result, future operations have to be performed using only these keywords.

This code takes approximately `47 seconds` to run 100 files. Now I was trying to think of a way to speed it up. There are ~50 elements in `keywords2`. So I thought I am basically running BETA 50 times by having it inside the function `func` when all I need for it is the list `keywords` and the `sentence`. I do have both of these already in the main code so I transferred this part to the main part of the code -

```
import os
keywords=['a','b']
keywords2=['c','d mvb']

def foo(sentence,k2):

    for k in gs_list:
        if (k in sentence) and (k2 in sentence):
            print 'a match'
    return 4

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(r'F:\M.Tech\for assigning cl\selected\random 100'):
    for file in files:
        sentences=open(file).readlines();
        for sentence in sentences:
            if sentence.startswith('!series_title'):   

                gs_list=[]                       #####
                for k in keywords:               #####    
                    if k in sentence:            #####
                        gs_list.append(k)        #####                        

                for k2 in keywords2:
                    foo(sentence,k2)
```

My thinking was that this would ensure that this list forming process happens only once for every sentence and not 50 times like before. This should definitely increase the speed of the code. But this code actually took `89 seconds` to go through the same 100 files.

I am unable to understand why this can take *more* time than the previous code. Any ideas?

Comment: Your examples aren't valid Python, could you give a working [mcve]?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, made the changes. Please have a look

Comment: @ChahatUpreti: if you copy and paste your code into a file, say `program.py`, and then type `python program.py` at the console, you'll see there are still syntax errors remaining.

Comment: @DSM,   now the code is running. please have a look